# Translating select option in rails I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I translate the below code in rails I18n

```
f.select :option,[["This is a Scam","Scam"],["This is a Spam","Spam"],["This is a bot","Bot"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`config/locales/es.yml`

```
es:
  helpers:
    model:
      select_attr:
        values:
          scam: 'estafa'
          spam: 'correo no deseado'
          bot: 'larva del moscardón'
```

`config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  helpers:
    model:
      select_attr:
        values:
          scam: 'Scam'
          spam: 'Spam'
          bot: 'Bot'
```

And modify your `select helper` to

```
= f.select :option, [
                     [I18n.t("helpers.model.select_attr.values.scam", 'Scam')], 
                     [I18n.t("helpers.model.select_attr.values.spam", 'Spam')], 
                     [I18n.t("helpers.model.select_attr.values.bot", 'Bot')]
                    ]
```

Rails set options values according to your selected locale (`en` or `es`) as in the example above.

First attribute of the option's inner array is a `label`, which will be show to user. Second - is an option `value`, which be saved to database field `option`.

More info you can read at [ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) docs page.

Comment: Thanks . Really I don't understand what is going here, So how do I add another item to the list and that is `values.scum, 'Scam'` representing thanks

Comment: @foliwe83 What is your select options? Does it model's constant or it related model? Can you post your model code here? I've a typo mistake in first answer, no I'll fix it.

Comment: My model is hard coded.  It is not a dynamic list this is exactly like so  `=f.select :option,[["This is a Scam","Scam"],["This is a Spam","Spam"],["This is a bot","Bot"]]`

Comment: @foliwe83 I've update my answer. I don't quite understand your problem, and if answer will not solve it, please add more details to your question.

Comment: Thanks, @cnnr The codes works. So how I can add the array of all the ?`spam,scam,bot` to the list because this  `[I18n.t("helpers.model.select_attr.values.scam", 'Scam')` displays only the value for scam but i want to have all the three options.Hope you understand

Comment: @foliwe83 Oh, now I see ) Completed answer should look like this, with full list of options. Glad to help you :)